# PostgreSQL: Alternative to UPDATE (As COPY to INSERT)

Tags: postgresql, insert-update

I realize update operation speed in PostgreSQL doesn't meet my expectation especially when I update so many row at the same time, said 10K rows data. Is there any fast alternative to UPDATE? as using fast COPY to INSERT operation.

Thanks before.

Comment: Are the fields in the where clause of your update not indexed, are you updating a lot of indexed fields or do you know of any other reason for slowness? Hard to know where the bottleneck is with so little info.

Comment: The fields are indexed, and right know we are using a function if the data is new it will be inserted otherwise we will update most of the fields. That's why I'm thinking to use another alternative to UPDATE just like COPY to INSERT operation because it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `INSERT`, `UPDATE` can optimize for large writes.  I have certainly had cases where I was updating tens of thousands of records and had it reasonably fast.  The normal caveats for bulk operations apply, of course:

1. Indexing doesn't always help and in fact will not help if updating your entire table.  You may find it faster to drop indexes, update, and recreate them.
2. NOT EXISTS is painfully slow in updates over large sets.  Find a way of making things work with a left join instead.
3. If Normal performance rules apply (please look at query plans, etc).